# Importing sbt file causes strange sources root

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a project that looks like:

```
my-project
  project/plugins.sbt
  build.sbt
  src
    main/scala/com/my-project/...
    test/scala/com/my-project/...
```

I've forked this from project that initially had a directory structure that looked like:

```
my-project
  project/plugins.sbt
  build.sbt
  src/com/my-project/...
```

with no test directory, so I tried to reorganize it to follow the standard Maven conventions. Adding the line

```
scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test" / "scala"
```

to `my-project/build.sbt` does what I expect, resulting in `myproject/src/test/scala` being marked as a test sources root when I hit "refresh all SBT projects" in the SBT tool window. However, no matter what I add, I can't get the sources root to move off of `my-project/src`. At the moment, I've added the following:

```
sourceDirectory := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "scala"
sourceDirectory in Scope.GlobalScope := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "scala"
sourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "scala"

scalaSource := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "scala"
scalaSource in Scope.GlobalScope :=  baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "scala"
scalaSource in Compile :=  baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "scala"

scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test" / "scala"
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using the latest (14.1.2) version of IntelliJ, with the Scala plugin, and version 0.13.8 of sbt.

EDIT: the original project is [hello-scaloid-sbt](https://github.com/pocorall/hello-scaloid-sbt), the original, unedited sbt file is there. In full, it is:

```
import android.Keys._

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")

android.Plugin.androidBuild

name := "hello-scaloid-sbt"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

proguardCache in Android ++= Seq(
  ProguardCache("org.scaloid") % "org.scaloid"
)

proguardOptions in Android ++= Seq("-dontobfuscate", "-dontoptimize", "-keepattributes Signature", "-printseeds target/seeds.txt", "-printusage target/usage.txt"
  , "-dontwarn scala.collection.**" // required from Scala 2.11.4
  , "-dontwarn org.scaloid.**" // this can be omitted if current Android Build target is android-16
)

libraryDependencies += "org.scaloid" %% "scaloid" % "4.0-RC1" withSources() withJavadoc()

scalacOptions in Compile += "-feature"

run <<= run in Android

install <<= install in Android

retrolambdaEnable in Android := false
```

The lines above (all of the scalaSource options, etc) have been inserted in between libraryDependencies and scalacOptions.

Comment: Can you show the code that setting up using `my-project/src`?

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote? And @Dale, I'm not clear what you mean by that

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the sbt setup before you started adding lines. SBT already follows the maven layout so you need to share something that is reproducible to be able to find an answer.

Comment: @DaleWijnand I've added a link to the complete setup before I made any changes. In the linked project, the source root is src/, rather than src/main. I can't find anything in either sbt file that is causing that to happen.

Comment: @DaleWijnand And edited again so that the original SBT file is included in the body of the question, rather than an external link -- I was on mobile earlier and wasn't able to put the whole thing in.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem was caused by the `android-sdk-plugin`, which had its own idea about where the sources root should be. I gave up and restructured my project so that `tests` is a top-level directory.

Comment: Actually, source location is determined by the location of AndroidManifest.xml